# Определить содержится ли значение в коллекции элементов выпадающего списка (ComboBox)

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, combobox

Есть некоторое строковое значение. Можно ли с помощью Linq запроса узнать, есть ли это значение в ComboBox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно через метод `Contains()`:

```
string s = "1";

comboBox1.Items.Add("1");
comboBox1.Items.Add("2");
comboBox1.Items.Add("3");

bool result = comboBox1.Items.Contains(s);
```

Comment: думаю, имеет смысл уточнить, что это не `Linq`- метод